# Samba file is read only in Windows, even with correct permissions in Linux for Group

Tags: linux, windows, samba, microsoft-excel

Windows keep seeing an Excel file as Read only for Group, the Linux permissions is correct for group to be read write.

Server OS Ubuntu 14.04.4, Client OS Windows 10, Samba 4.3.11

This is the Samba config file for the share.

```
[SHARENAME]
force create mode = 660
valid users = @GROUPNAME
force group = GROUPNAME
force security mode = 660
create mode = 660
path = /var/SHAREPATH
delete readonly = yes
security mask = 660
force directory mode = 2770
force directory security mode = 2770
directory mode = 2770
writeable = yes
directory security mask = 2770
create mask = 660
directory mask = 2770
```

I ran the following command to update the permissions on the shared folder.

```
find SHAREPATH -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
find SHAREPATH -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
```

Here is a list of the files in the folder.

```
drwxrws---   2 user1 groupname  4096 Aug  3 15:35 .
drwxrws---  10 user1 groupname  4096 Aug  3 11:25 ..
-rw-rw----+  1 user1 groupname 20516 Aug  3 10:44 file1.xlsx
-rw-rw----+  1 user1 groupname 20989 Aug  3 10:44 file2.xlsx
-rw-rw----+  1 user1 groupname 21010 Aug  3 11:11 file3.xlsx
-rw-rw----+  1 user1 groupname 21541 Aug  3 11:22 file4.xlsx
-rw-rwx---+  1 user2 groupname 21032 Aug  3 15:34 file5.xlsx
```

In that list file3 and file4 is Read only in Excel rest of files I can edit as I want. My own user is user2.

Here is the screenshot of what Windows think the group permissions are.

[Windows permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXxM4.jpg)

From what I understand Windows will see the wrong permissions until I Disconnect and reconnect. Steps I have taken already include. Restart Windows, Restart Linux, Restart Samba Service.

Any advice would be appreciated.